# Update the axis of dynamic subplot after hold on

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a figure which plot 2 subplots(three graphs). The second subplot is hold to plot a scatter graph. As both my subplots is dynamically changed with the value of `x` and `y`, how to set the axis of the third plot(scatter plot) on the subplot number 2, without disturb the subplot number 2?

```
subplot 211; imshow(I1(y:y+10,x:x+30), 'InitialMagnification','fit'); %plot #1
subplot 212; imshow(I2(y:y+10,x:x+30), 'InitialMagnification','fit'); %plot #2
hold on; scatter(somevalue_x, somevalue_y); %plot #3 on plot #2
axis([y y+10 x x+30]); %this line will change the axis of plot #2 too
hold off;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `hold on` results that the next plot command adds more data into the current plot, not a new plot.  You don't have three plots here.

Comment: if `axis([y y+10 x x+30])` is removed, I'll have three plots, where plot #3 is on top on plot #2. Any way to tweak the code to make it work like described?

Comment: No, you'll still have two data series in non-overlapping areas of the second plot, which will be clear if you turn on axis lines and  labels.  I suggest you just do `scatter(somevalue_x - x, somevalue_y - y)` in order to shift the scatter data series onto the top of the image data series.